# Infix, Interfix, suffix and the Italian morphology (English definitions)

Tags: grammar

I am writing a short summary of the Italian morphological system for my thesis.

I am struggling with how I should define certain morphemes using English.

Future –er- in “am-**er**-emo”.

Now, “-emo” is a suffix (a person-number marker).

Is “-er-” an infix, an interfix or a suffix?

And what about “-in-” in tavol-in-o?

Is it infix, an interfix or a suffix?

thanks

P.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I am reluctant to send away people who ask good questions (we are rather question-starved here), but you might get a more authoritative answer at [linguistics.stackexchange.com](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

This looks more like a question about English terminology than about Italian language, and as such it would be off topic. Italian grammar only considers *prefissi* (at the beginning of a word), *suffissi* (at the end) and *infissi* (in the middle);<sup>1</sup> apparently – but this should be asked about in an English-language site about general linguistics (such as https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) – this corresponds in English to the distinction among prefixes, suffixes, and infixes.

As for “interfix”, I admit I never heard about it and more than one English dictionary don't include it, but apparently, if we [trust Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfix), it is “a phoneme which is placed in between two morphemes and does not have a semantic meaning”. With this definition, none of your examples is an interfix, since those strings of letters: a) are not single phonemes; and, more importantly, b) do have a semantic meaning. Indeed, *-er-* in *ameremo* characterises the future tense, while *-in-* denotes a diminutive form (*tavolo* = “table”; *tavolino* = “small table”).

<sup>1</sup> See for instance the article “affissazione” in G.L. Beccaria, ed., *Dizionario di linguistica*, Einaudi.